# How to solve "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" in my case in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dynamic-sql

I am trying to make dynamics query using date, I don't know what is wrong

**Actual Data of Time Field from SALES Table**

```
Department  Time        ExtendedPrice
-------------------------------------
Toys        2018-11-01      1205.11
Toys        2018-12-02      1230.27
Baby Care   2018-12-01      6797.95
Sports      2019-01-01      365.8
Sports      2019-01-01      2993.44
Sports      2018-12-02      580.03
Baby Care   2019-01-02      1117.92
Baby Care   2019-01-02      390.75
soap        2018-11-01      3275.25
Baby Care   2018-12-01      367.56
```

the above date is sample format of actual data

```
DECLARE @cols AS Varchar(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(MAX),Time,105)+''
                      FROM #Sales
                      GROUP by Time
                      ORDER by Time

               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
               ,1,1,'')
```

**Output**

```
select @cols
//output
01-11-2018,02-11-2018,01-12-2018,02-12-2018,01-01-2019,02-01-2019
```

**@query**

```
DECLARE @query AS Varchar(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT 
                    ' + @cols + '
              FROM 
              (
                   SELECT 
                       convert(varchar(MAX),Time,105) Time,
                       ExtendedPrice
                   FROM 
                       #Sales
              ) x
              pivot 
              (
                  sum(ExtendedPrice)
                  for Time in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p '
PRINT @query
```

it shows error following error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**UPDATE**

I tried also this

```
DECLARE @cols AS Varchar(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',[' + convert(varchar(MAX),Time,105)+']'
                FROM #Sales
                GROUP by Time
                ORDER by Time
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

    select @cols

//output
[01-11-2018],[02-11-2018],[01-12-2018],[02-12-2018],[01-01-2019],[02-01-2019]
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Don't you think the output of `@Cols` should looks like `'01-11-2018','02-11-2018','01-12-2018','02-12-2018','01-01-2019','02-01-2019'`? or even `[01-11-2018],[02-11-2018],[01-12-2018],[02-12-2018],[01-01-2019],[02-01-2019]`? in other way `STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(MAX),Time,105))`

Comment: @Sami I will check your code also. And see my updates

Comment: @Sami when i run your code it shows the same error and also `@cols` output is `[01-11-2018],[02-11-2018],[01-12-2018],[02-12-2018],[01-01-2019],[02-01-2019]`

Comment: @Liamneesan I don't think so **[`Live Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=37f249d41fa7dc1102b527e1577e9102)**

Comment: @Sami Excellent. Thank you. Make it in answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Quote the dates as

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Department] varchar(9), [Time] datetime, [ExtendedPrice] int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([Department], [Time], [ExtendedPrice])
VALUES
    ('Toys', '2018-11-01 00:00:00', 1205.11),
    ('Toys', '2018-12-02 00:00:00', 1230.27),
    ('Baby Care', '2018-12-01 00:00:00', 6797.95),
    ('Sports', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', 365.8),
    ('Sports', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', 2993.44),
    ('Sports', '2018-12-02 00:00:00', 580.03),
    ('Baby Care', '2019-01-02 00:00:00', 1117.92),
    ('Baby Care', '2019-01-02 00:00:00', 390.75),
    ('soap', '2018-11-01 00:00:00', 3275.25),
    ('Baby Care', '2018-12-01 00:00:00', 367.56)
;

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Time, 105))
                      FROM T
                      GROUP by Time
                      ORDER by Time
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
               ,1,1,'');

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=
             N'SELECT 
                    ' + @cols + '
              FROM 
              (
                   SELECT 
                       convert(varchar(10),Time,105) Time,
                       ExtendedPrice
                   FROM 
                       T
              ) x
              pivot 
              (
                  sum(ExtendedPrice)
                  for Time in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p ';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 01-11-2018 | 01-12-2018 | 02-12-2018 | 01-01-2019 | 02-01-2019 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|       4480 |       7164 |       1810 |       3358 |       1507 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3d2c09c7574ec6400aceebbb7d15d34)**

Comment: I need your help. I want to make sum of all previous days `(01-11-2018) + (01-12-2018) + (01-01-2019)` and NextDays `(02-11-2018) + (02-12-2018) + (02-01-2019)`

Comment: @Liamneesan Just **[`click here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)** and fill the forms, then you will get answers not just one cause this is another question :)

Comment: give me a min. I will make new question and text you, that question will be continuity of this question

Comment: can you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393710/how-to-convert-into-column-with-certain-case-in-sql-using-dynamics-query)